# can't use integer at timer interval

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, intervals, timespan

I'm using WPF and the timer doesn't allow to use int for interval. Instead, it asks for TimeSpan

```
timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedItem));
```

So I changed my code to this but at runtime it gives me an InvalidCastException, saying that the object cannot be converted from System.Windows.Controls.ComboboxItem to System.IConvertible.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is the value of `comboBox1.SelectedItem` ?

Comment: You should be using bindings... but try `SelectedValue` instead.

Comment: combobox items are from 1000 to 10000 jumping 500's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this

```
Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedText)
```

The `comboBox1.SelectedItem` corresponds to the selected item of the ComboBox control and not with the text of it, which is that you want.

Specifically, the `SelectedText` property of a CombBox control

> Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.

as it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Update**

Please use this one:

```
((ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Or in two steps:

```
ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(item.Content.ToString()));
```

For more information about the `ComboBoxItem` class, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Oops I made an error. Please see my updated post and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I wanted to try that too but in WPF there is no property like that

Comment: Please give me then a few minutes to see what's wrong. Thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are adding ComboBoxItems directly to your ComboBox.

A cleaner and safer approach than parsing strings would be to continue binding to SelectedItem, but to also bind the ItemsSource to a collection of integers.

Then use the ItemTemplate property of the ComboBox to define how to render the integers if you are not satisfied with the default ToString() rendering.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Intervals}" SelectedItem="{SelectedInterval}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Int64}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<ComboBox>
```

With properties looking something like this:

```
public int SelectedInterval {get;set;}

public List<int> Intervals {
    get {
        var lst = new List<int>();
        for(var i = 1000; i <= 10000; i += 500)
        {
            lst.Add(i);
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

Now you have strongly type properties that you can manipulate without parsing.